# NoSuchMethodException in cocos2d-android in CCCallFunc

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android, nosuchmethoderror

I am using cocos2d for android (ZhouWeikuan version). The CCCallFunc is not working anywhere. It is always throwing NoSuchMethodException. 
A code snippet

```
...
CCJumpBy action7 = CCJumpBy.action(0.4f, CGPoint.ccp(60f,0f), 30f, 1);
        CCJumpBy action8 = CCJumpBy.action(0.4f, CGPoint.ccp(-60f,0f), 30f, 1);
        CCCallFuncN action9 = CCCallFuncN.action(this,"stopDancing");
        CCSequence action10 = CCSequence.actions(action1,action2,action3,action4,action5,action6,action7,action8,action9);
        this.runAction(action10);
...
```

"stopDancing" is in the same class. I think there is a problem in this.

Comment: You should post the stack trace and the stopDancing method. My bet would be a problem on the parameters of the stopDancing method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your method as **public** which contains one **argument as Object**

so your method will looks like this

```
public void stopDancing(Object sender){    
//Your code...
......    
}
```